# How to print colorful and bold string in the mini-buffer

Tags: shell

When I do `echo "\033[1;31mThis is bold red text\033[0m"` it should print `This is bold red text` as red and bold. When I try it in the emacs's shell it prints it as it is instead showing the ansi-color.

example:

`M-x shell-command` and `echo "\033[1;31mThis is bold red text\033[0m"` enter.

=> How could I fix this?

my setup:

```
(require 'ansi-color)
(defun colorize-compilation-buffer ()
  (toggle-read-only)
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))
  (toggle-read-only))
(add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'colorize-compilation-buffer)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on) ;;
```

---

Please note that: output is printed in the minibuffer, I am not sure can color could be shown in the minibuffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the `M-x shell`, the `M-x shell-command` does not provide color.

You can write your own, e.g.,

```
M-x your-shell-command echo "\033[1;31mThis is bold red text\033[0m"
```

```
(require 'ansi-color)                   ; for `ansi-color-apply-on-region'
(require 'subr-x)                       ; for `string-trim-right'

(defun your-ansi-color-apply (s)
  "Like `ansi-color-apply' but use `face' instead of `font-lock-face'."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert s)
    (let ((ansi-color-apply-face-function
           (lambda (beg end face)
             (when face
               (put-text-property beg end 'face face)))))
      (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max)))
    (buffer-string)))

(defun your-shell-command (command)
  "A simplified `shell-command' to support color."
  (interactive (list (read-shell-command "Shell command: ")))
  (message "%s"
           (string-trim-right
            (your-ansi-color-apply
             (shell-command-to-string command)))))
```

`your-ansi-color-apply` is required because the echo area does not support Font Lock mode thus `font-lock-face` won't work.

Comment: Sorry for pretty late comment; I have a python script like `from rich import print; print("[italic red]Hello[/italic red] World!")` (https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html#quick-start) which does not show the color output ; should I ask a new question related to this?

Comment: @alper If the standard M-! also show no color, that's because the python rich library doesn't the you're using a terminal, see also https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/console.html#terminal-detection

Comment: Nice catch, having `force_terminal=True` in the rich constructor solved it. The only thing now is that ansi-colors does not match with the Terminals' original colors. Like red color is not same as the Terminal's defined red color